# htaccess rewrite rule for loading image from another domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-5

I am developing a multidomian admin panel in laravel. 
All domians are on same server. 
We upload images for specific domain inside admin panel example.com 
image: example.com/uploads/domainname/image.jpg

now inside domainname.com i want to use

```
<img src="domainname.com/uploads/image.jpg" >
```

instead of

```
<img src="example.com/uploads/domainname/image.jpg" >
```

approach i am using for this is 
i have a controller responsible for getting image content

```
domainname.com/image?path=uploads/domainname/image.jpg
```

and then i am using htaccess

```
AliasMatch "^/uploads/$"   "/home/dir/public_html/example/public/uploads/$1"

RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ image?path=uploads/domainname/$1
```

but it's not working. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I can't follow. You write "i have a controller responsible for getting image content", but where is it?  How does that relate to the Alias and Rewrite lines following? Now are you using a controller or are you trying to rewrite?

Comment: Also, is folder named `/domainname/`  or `/domainname.com/`, and if it is not full domain namet, do you only handle `.com` domain names?

Comment: folder is /domainname/

Comment: @arkascha i dont want to use domainname.com/image?path=uploads/domainname/image.jpg in image sourse

Comment: Which is fine but does not answer my question.

Comment: @arkascha for you let me rephrase my question:
my images are in example.com i want to use them in domainname.com but i want to see example.com in image src="example.com/uploades/domainname/image.jpg"
i want src="domainname.com/uploades/domainname/image.jpg"

Comment: That is all fine and I understood that much from your question. I asked about that controller you mention. And how you want to approach that task: by using a controller or by rewriting. You cannot do both...

Comment: by rewriting
that's why i have asked this question. i don't want to use controller url to pull the image content in image src.